# php mysql How to Run a Subquery in the right way for this table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query two tables that have foreign keys in each other to display conditional results, my tables are as follow:

auction_bids table:

```
id applicant_id bid auction_id owner.id
```

auctions table:

```
id user_id title description
```

The result I need to display to the logged in user is:

```
title applicant_id [how many bids the project has] auction_id
```

My current not working query is:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(auction_bids.owner_id)
          FROM auction_bids 
         WHERE auction_bids.owner_id = ".$_SESSION['userid']."
       ) AS count, auction_bids.* 
  FROM auction_bids 
 WHERE auction_bids.owner_id = ".$_SESSION['userid']."
```

i cannot get how many bids each auction has in the database along with the title
Thank you

Comment: [Don't forget **to take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use SO](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This one will list all applicants and their total bids on all auctions the selected user have:**

```
   SELECT a.title, b.applicant_id, COUNT(b.applicant_id) AS bids, a.id
     FROM auction_bids b
     JOIN auctions a ON a.id = b.auction_id
    WHERE b.owner_id = ".$_SESSION['userid']."
 GROUP BY b.applicant_id
```

[**See a live DEMO here.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a544e/37/0)

Keep in mind you on your question you have `owner.id` like that while here I have it with an underscore `owner_id` change it as you need.

According to your comments on the other reply you may want a different result per auction from what you propose on your question.

**This one will list all auctions from a user with the total bids, auction title and id:**

```
   SELECT a.title, COUNT(b.applicant_id) AS total_bids, a.id
     FROM auction_bids b
     JOIN auctions a ON a.id = b.auction_id
    WHERE b.owner_id = ".$_SESSION['userid']."
 GROUP BY b.auction_id
```

[**See a live DEMO here.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/812e2/3/0)

Comment: i used this one and i only changed procedure then it work just fine.
thank you so much. i want to point up but it says i don't have enough point for it. thanks a lot again all of you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT a.title, ab.applicant_id, COUNT(*), a.id
FROM auction a JOIN
     auction_bids ab
     ON a.id = ab.auction_id
WHERE a.user_id = ".$_SESSION['userid']."
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: thanks Gordon but that is counting the wrong one. i need how many bids there are on a single auction posted by owner_id

Comment: @Justin . . . Can't an owner have more than one auction?  How are you passing in the auction id?

Comment: yes he does this is where i am getting stuck. lets say MIKE has 4 auctions and first auction has 10 bids and second has 20, third has 5 and the fourth has 40 bids. MIKE should see this when he logs in:
title: auction1, bids: 10 auction_id-1
title: auction2, bids:20 auction_id-2
title: auction3, bids:5 auction_id-3
title: auction4, bids:40 auction_id-4
i won't need the applicant id

Comment: @Justin . . . That is what the current version of the answer should be doing.

Comment: i will try it now one more